# encrypt a number to another number in a specific field

Tags: encryption

for example, now I want to encrypt my birthday 19960609, if I using some other format-preserving encryption, I will get a number that is not like a birthday. However, I want to my encrypted birthday like 19870928 which is in a specific field.
take birthday for example, the field is like [19000101,20191117].
I want to know is there any solution to encrypt one number to another number in a specific field, and this encrypted birthday could go back to the original value as well.

Comment: When used correctly, format-preserving encryption **is** the solution to your problem. But you must make sure the output range is exactly the numbers that look like a valid date, and no others.

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to design this module.. kind of difficult

Answer (score 0):

You might want to search for the term `encoding`. The string "19960609" is just an encoded representation of the date value 09/06/1996.

To give you an idea of an algorithm (a variation of [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)):

```
// find the number of days between the start of your interval and the to be encoded date
a := COUNT_DAYS_BETWEEN(19960609, 19000101)
// find thesize of your interval
b := COUNT_DAYS_BETWEEN(19000101, 20191117)
// add or subtract a choosen number 
c := a - 3567 
// take care that it still fits into your interval
d := MODULO(c, b)
```

As the algorithm just shifts the birthday by some choosen days it's reversable. Feel free to replace the operation in c with a more complex algorithm.